# Global Section Functor Existence for Pre(Co)Sheaves?

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors

I currently have a co-presheaf  F : Top -> Vect. I don't know how to cosheafify it.
It is well-known that the Global section functor for sheaves is a covariant left exact functor (right exact for cosheaves). Is this also defined for a (co) presheaf?

Answer (score 1):

A (co)presheaf on a space $X$ is the same thing as a (co)sheaf on the space $Y$ whose underlying set is the set of all open subsets of $X$, with a basis for the open subsets of $Y$ being the sets of the form $d(U)=\{V\in Y:V\subseteq U\}$ for each open subset $U\subseteq X$.  In $Y$, no basic open set $d(U)$ can be written as a union of strictly smaller basic open sets (since none of them can contain the point $U$), and it follows that any functor on the poset of basic open sets extends uniquely to a (co)sheaf.  But such a functor is just a (co)presheaf on $X$, so you get an equivalence between the category of (co)presheaves on $X$ and the category of (co)sheaves on $Y$.

So if you know that the global sections functor is left (right) exact on (co)sheaves on any space, you automatically get the same result for (co)presheaves on any space.

(Incidentally, I have not thought about it myself much, but according to the answers to [this question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120729/cosheafification), describing the cosheafification of copresheaves (or even proving that it exists) seems to be quite nontrivial.)

Comment: Thanks! Yes the cosheafification business seems very interesting but thankfully not necessary for me...